# How to iterate over current row in an excel sheet using column name?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xssf

I need to parse over an excel sheet and retrieve values from each row to store it in database. Currently I am doing it based on the type of values that each cell holds. This is ok in the current case as I have to deal with only 2 columns. But I have a new requirement to parse an excel sheet that holds more than 12 columns. How can it be done in this case? Is there a way I could iterate each row based on column if I am using a structured table with table headers?

My current code is as follows.

```
        File file = new File(UPLOAD_LOCATION + fileUpload.getFile().getOriginalFilename());
        FileInputStream excelFile = new FileInputStream(file);

        Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelFile);
        Sheet datatypeSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Iterator<Row> iterator = datatypeSheet.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Row currentRow = iterator.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = currentRow.iterator();

            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {

                Cell currentCell = cellIterator.next();
                // getCellTypeEnum shown as deprecated for version 3.15
                // getCellTypeEnum ill be renamed to getCellType starting
                // from version 4.0
                if (currentCell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.STRING) {
                    System.out.print(currentCell.getStringCellValue() + "--");
                } else if (currentCell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.NUMERIC) {
                    System.out.print(currentCell.getNumericCellValue() + "--");
                }

            }
```

I am using the following external apache API imports:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
```

Is there a way I can do the same passing in the name of column headers?

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need it as an iterator ? could the normal loop be a problem ?

Comment: @BasilBattikhi Not a problem. Is there a way doing so?

Comment: Grab the values in row 1, create a map from row 1 cell values to their column numbers, then process the other rows looking up column to row 1 value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

based on the comments

```
    InputStream excelFile = new FileInputStream(file);
    Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelFile);
    ArrayList colsList=new ArrayList();
    colsList.add("Col1");
    colsList.add("Col2");
    colsList.add("Col3");
    colsList.add("Col4");
    Sheet datatypeSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    int numOfRows=datatypeSheet.getLastRowNum();
    for(int rowNum=0;rowNum<numOfRows;rowNum++){
    Row row=datatypeSheet.getRow(rowNum);
    int numOfCellPerRow=row.getLastCellNum();
    for(int cellNum=0;cellNum<numOfCellPerRow;cellNum++){
    if(colsList.contains(row.getCell(rowNum).getStringCellValue())){
    Cell cell=row.getCell(cellNum)
    System.out.println("Cell No:"+cellNum+" value is: 
    "+cell.getStringCellValue())
    }
   }
     System.out.println("This is a new Row");
   }
```

Comment: Thank you for posting, but this is not actually what I want. I need to get the values in each column using the column name. I can use a structured reference table if that is necessary.